# Linear model between data with standard error

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model

I have two set of data from a experiment. I would like to evaluate a linear model between both sets. However, the term corresponding to y variable is composed by two elements: The measure and its standard error. In this case, how i can undertake a linear regression? The data i try to evaluate are the following:

x                   y                   sd_y

0.230            1.4996             0.0311

0.385            1.3890             0.0348

0.230            1.4809             0.0599

0.385            1.8336             0.0673

0.150            1.2984             0.0446

0.310            1.5255             0.0791

0.465            1.1892             0.0411

0.310            1.1906             0.0443

0.310            1.0706             0.0296

Comment: Welcome to cv :-). Where does the information about $sd_y$ come from? What is the aim of this linear regression, prediction or just fitting parameters, or some inference on slope and intercept?

Comment: I want to evaluate the dependency between the variables. The standard errors were estimated from the measurements that comprised each reading.

Comment: Thank you for the information - do you know how the standard errors were estimated? was this repeated measurements? Then it would be good to know how many repetitions. I can see that the $x$ values occur in multiplicity - is the data set that you show whole data, or a part of it? It would be good if you say this in your question - it helps to decide which method to use :-).

Comment: The data were taken in different experiments. Some of such test were undertaken with the same x-variable. In case of y- variables, they were obtained from linear regression models from data measured in each experiment. For be more clear, the y-variables represents the slope of least-square model of the data measured inside each experiment. Therefore, the SDy represents the error of the slope.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this fully - what tests? What do you want to find out from your data? The solution that @alexis_thual suggests, to just run another linear model on the data, may do the job. However, when I plot the data you gave in the question, I cannot see much structure in them. Do you want to test if all slopes from the experiments are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents you from running a linear regression here. You will end up with 2 coefficients (+ 2 other if you include intercepts): one trying to linearly explain `y` from `x`, and the other doing the same for `sd_y`.

Using `sklearn` in python, it would look something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = np.array([
    0.230,
    0.385,
    0.230,
    0.385,
    0.150,
    0.310,
    0.465,
    0.310,
    0.310,
]).reshape(-1, 1)

y_and_sd_y = np.array([
    [1.4996, 0.0311],
    [1.3890, 0.0348],
    [1.4809, 0.0599],
    [1.8336, 0.0673],
    [1.2984, 0.0446],
    [1.5255, 0.0791],
    [1.1892, 0.0411],
    [1.1906, 0.0443],
    [1.0706, 0.0296],
])

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x, y_and_sd_y)

# Explore learnt beta coefficients
print(reg.coef_)

# Explore intercepts as well
print(reg.intercept_)
```

```
[[0.00859018]
 [0.00450328]]
```

```
[1.38372914 0.04658927]
```

Comment: Welcome to cv alexis_thual - a quick solution, and probably the one that fits the needs :-) (+1)
@handelsarache, I was just wondering if the information about sd(y) should be used in a particular way with the model.